# slide down effect with jquery

Tags: jquery

suppose i have one div which has data. i want when i will click on a button then a new div will be created and which will cover the actual div like shutter down. here is sample code i got from a site which is very close but not the way i want.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var $box = $('#box')
    .wrap('<div id="box-outer"></div>');
  $('#blind').click(function() {
    $box.blindToggle('slow');  
  });    
});
```

check the demo of above code http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/02/simple-effects-plugins
just go to site and click on blind toggle button just to see how i want the things.
i want when button will be click then a new div will be created and the new div will cover the actual div with slide down effect and when i will click again then new div will slide up.how to implement it using jquery. guide me with sample code if possible. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you've provided pretty much have the code already for you. You just need a few tweaks.

**demo**:
http://jsfiddle.net/dACjL/

Comment: thanks....your code is pretty much close but do change bit in ur code like that box div initially will not cover the data div when i will click on button first time then box div will slide down & cover "data-box" and when i will click again on button then box-div will slide up and uncover the data-div. please do the change in ur code. thanks for good code.

Comment: i change the css bit here so now it is working as i want. change is here like <div id="box" style="margin-top: -120px; ">Blind me up.
    Blind me up. Blind me up.
    </div> i change the margin-top from 0px to -120px. so now it is giving me the right smell. thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are already native function [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [`.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) which do what you want.

---

**Update:** Not sure if i understood it correctly but, here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k45KP/).

Comment: yes i know .i tried but could not simulate what i want. i want when button will be click then a new div will be created and the new div will cover the actual div with slide down effect and when i will click again then new div will slide up. can u plzz help me with code.

Comment: @Thomas, I can help you with the code, but let me know what you want first. Can you a simple picture showing what you want?

Comment: just go to site i gave the link here in my question. then u can see what i want. in my case a new div will cover my actual big div with slide down effect.

Comment: u r pretty much close but i found something need to be change like "box red" div height & width should be same like box div. when i click then "box red" div will cover box div with slide down effect. this code is pretty much close what i want http://jsfiddle.net/dACjL/

Answer (score 0):

Use `slideUp()` and `slideDown` Functions.

`$('selector').slideUp()` check here http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

and `$('selector').slideDown()` check here http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: i am aware of slideUP() and slideDown() function. but how to cover my actual div with new div using native function like slideUP() and slideDown(). can u advise me with sample code if possible.

Comment: u will have to add that new div after a particular selector using `after()` and will have to append the actual div into that new called div. Try it will help with that.